# Can I use .NET with classic ASP?

Tags: .net, asp-classic

Due to a customer requirement I am forced to use classic ASP, so I am wondering if I could use .Net (or maybe JScript which as new features) to try to add some advanced features.

I really would like a decent way to connect to SQL Server. How to do it?

Amazingly the customer relented and would like to go with ASP.Net now.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I've got to hear what that customer requirement is.

Comment: His requirement is use ASP.  The rest is the usual web development stuff.  I just hate to suffer using ADO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some links for you to try

1) [.NET COM+ Interop Component with Classic ASP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/Net_COM__Interop.aspx)

2) [Consume a .NET Assembly from a classic ASP page.](http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/archive/2004/01/31/65330.aspx)

Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, not what I wanted to have to do, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JScript for the page scripting language on new pages, but you can't directly use .NET to add new features to classic ASP.   Depending on what you need to do, you can write a .net assembly and access it as a COM component, but there is a strong possibility that this is more trouble than it's worth.

Since you talked about accessing SQL Server in classic ASP, I would look [here](http://www.vb6.us/guides/vb6-database-guide).  It may at least point you in the right direction, depending on what you know about classic ASP and visual basic 6.

Comment: +1 For answering my other question about JScript.  Can you still use the try catch in JScript for the server side?

Comment: yep!  It sure beats onErrorResume next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AspCompat="true" in the aspx page, which makes it compatible with classic asp. The n you can write classic asp type scripting.
check out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx

Comment: Please don't post .NET 1.1 links unless someone explicitly asks for them.

Comment: I don't think this answers what's being asked.